# Is the space of random variables w/ finite variance a Hilbert Space?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose we are in the space of absolutely continuous random variables with mean zero and finite variance, $V$. It is equipped with the norm $\sigma:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+, \sigma(X) = \sqrt{ \int x^2 f_X(x) dx }$ (that is, the norm is the standard deviation), and the inner product $(X,Y) = \int xy f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy$.

Can we say that $V$ is a Hilbert Space? That is, is it separable and complete? What is the countable dense basis if it is seperable?

Please tell me if I am erroneous anywhere - I am coming up with this with a one-semester background in measure theory and an undergrad class in probability, attempting to draw connections, so I might miss out some details.

Comment: I encourage you to check that the norm you defined is not given by the square root of the inner product that you defined.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! It should be correct now?

Comment: Your $\sigma(X)$ is not the standard deviation but rather the $L^2$ norm.

Comment: If mean is 0, aren't they equivalent?

Comment: You need to prove the completeness of this space.

Comment: That is my question though...

Comment: Why should be a Hilbert space be separable? Read the definition of  a Hilbert space.

Comment: Stein and Shakarchi, Real Analysis, page 161-162: "A set H is a Hilbert Space if it satisfies the following ... (vi) H is separable" - I am following this definition.

Comment: To show that your space is complete, you only need to show that it is closed in $L^2$. In particular,  you need to show that an $L^2$ limit of absolutely continuous random variables is absolutely continuous. I don't know whether this is true. Actually it's definitely false.

Comment: Your comment gives me no new information. Would you have a proof or, more feasibly, a source I can refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be an arbitrary measure space. Let
$$V = \{X \in L^2_{\mathbb{R}}(\Omega, \mu) : X \text{ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure and } E(X) = 0\}.$$
We want to know whether $V$ is a Hilbert space when regarded as a subspace of the Hilbert space $L^2_{\mathbb{R}}(\Omega, \mu)$. There are several problems though. One problem is that $0 \notin V$ because $0$ is not absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue measure. Another problem is that $V$ is not complete, because one can find $X_n \in V$ such that $X_n \to 0 \notin V$ in $L^2$. For example, take any $X \in V$, and set $X_n = \frac{1}{n}X$.

Comment: Could you explain why $0$ is not absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue measure, or refer me to a source? Sorry, it's a new notion for me!

Comment: @AryanDugar Look at any measure theory book for the definition of absolutely continuous, e.g. page 13 of https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf. $0$ is not absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue measure because $P(0 = 0) = 1$ and $m(\{0\}) = 0$.